# Finding similar numbers in two arrays then have a linked cell in a third array

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel I have three arrays. When I match values in array 1 and array 2, I want to copy the cell in array 3 (that is in the same row as the match in array 2) to a new cell.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? Is array three already filled? Are the two arrays basically filled columns? It would be great if you provide a screenshot with the desired input and output.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiquity.  My first array are dates are formatted as such with each cell filled.  My second array has dates but also contained blank cells.  I want to obtain the information in the cell next to array 2 that corresponds to array 1 and paste it in a fourth cell.

Comment: Again, a screenshot of your desired input and output would help. Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://i.imgur.com/36CHp7i.png Or more what Michal wrote?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating a 3rd hidden column that is a concatenation of array1 and array2 to the left of array3.  Then you can concatenate your input in the formula and do a simple VLOOKUP.

```
=iferror( vlookup( concatinate( <input1>, <input2>), <table>, 2, False), <err condition>)
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the most straightforward approach - note however that in the case of numbered data like this, "6 & 71" would result in the same value as "67 & 1", so your data would need to be formatted in such a way that you wouldn't have that type of 'before and after' mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a value is in an array can be done with ISNUMBER(MATCH()).
The result [above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErwJV.png)
Can be achieved with `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$8,0)),C1,"")` which checks whether it's anywhere in the array and prints column three if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming arrays 1, 2 & 3 *(including headers)* are located at`B6:B27`, `C6:C27` & `D6:D27` *(adjust as required)*

At least 3 formulas will return the required results:

- **Formula 1** : Enter this formula in `F7` then copy till last record:

  ```
  =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($C7,$B$7:$B$27,1,0)),"",$D7)
  ```
- **Formula 2** : Enter this formula in `G7` then copy till last record:

  ```
  =IF(ISNA(MATCH($C7,$B$7:$B$27,0)),"",$D7)
  ```
- **Formula 3** : Enter this Formula in `H7` then copy till last record:

  ```
  =IF(ISNA(MATCH($C$7:$C$27,$B$7:$B$27,0)),"",$D$7:$D$27)
  ```

[image]